# assembly illegal indexing mode DOSBOX

Tags: assembly, x86, dosbox

```
.model  small
.stack  100H
.data
A   db   'This is   a  test   $'
B   db   100 dup('$')
.code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
mov dx,offset A
mov cx,0000h
mov al,'$'
mov ah,' '
strt:
cmp al,[dx]
JE sof
cmp ah,[dx]
JE addd
jmp strt
addd:
inc dx
inc cx
sof:
.exit
end
```

I got two illegal indexing mode errors in the two `cmp` lines .

Comment: Check typo and mark code ba adding four spaces in front of each line

Comment: That's because there's no such addressing mode as `[dx]`. In 16-bit mode assembly you're restricted to only using certain combinations of base and index registers.

Comment: [16-bit addressing modes](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH04/CH04-2.html#HEADING2-23)